# How to append encoded parameters to the url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, url-encoding

I have a search input box and I am appending its data to an URL after the "#", e.g `http://test.cl.com/#pqr xyz` (using hash to avoid reloading of page). It is working fine but my data is not encoded as space is not replaced with `+` or `%20` So before appending I am using the `encodeURI` function and then appending that value to the URL but still in the address bar there is the space character. Before assigning I have checked that I am appending the correct value (by alerting `prq%20xyz`).

Current output: `http://test.cl.com/#pqr xyz`
Required output : `http://test.cl.com/#pqr+xyz`

Please help me to find out the cause of the prob. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#btn').click(function(){
             var url = encodeURI("pqr xyz");
              alert(url); // shows encoded value
             window.location.hash = (url);  
         });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>        

        <h3>sample app</h3>
        <button id="btn">
            append
        </button>


</body>
```

Comment: Just an additional comment: you don't need to alert strings or object to confirm there contents or state. You can use console.log(url); and it will pop up in the console of google chrome and firefox (not sure about IE).

Comment: Can not understand: what is the problem? In the browser replaces the "+" or "%20" for space in the address bar? You really is important? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you run your test on Firefox. Modern versions of Firefox don't encode space character in hash url to `%20` or `+`.

You can do a simply test just by adding a hash with spaces to any url.

Other browsers will automaticaly  convert space to `%20`, but not modern Firefox. And there is nothing wrong about it and shouldn't make any problems in your app.

If you decode the hash using `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` - the space will be decoded properly, so application will behave the same way like with `%20`.

The worst case is `+` character which is not decoded back to a space by `decodeURI`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the address bar is showing the unencoded characters doesn't mean that your data isn't properly encoded. Firefox (for example), can and will try to decode characters in the url address, to make it more human readable (I guess).

Even if you will input some encoded characters by hand, for example navigate to:

```
http://google.com?opt=test%20me%20or%20not
```

The url visible in the address bar will be "decoded" - you won't see %20.

EDIT:
To get the plus sign instead of %20 you can manually replace spaces for those before using encodeURI:

```
var url = encodeURI("pqr xyz".replace(/\s/, '+'));
```

Comment: In case of gmail its works fine. e.g  suppose you searched "pqr xyz" then in the url "pqr+xyz" will be appended (Firefox).

Comment: But is this a problem of what is visible in the browser address bar, or do you have some problems accessing / manipulating that data?

Comment: Thanks for example. i agree %20  will not be visible. so how can i achieve format like pqr+xyz after appending the encoded parameter.(same as gmail search or stackoverflow search). As in my case in the url space will appear which is nt a valid url (space is not allowed)

Comment: If you're insisting on using + character instead of %20 you can do something as simple as:

    var url = encodeURI("pqr xyz".replace(/\s/, '+'));

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following post. It has a test form where you can see the output of each of the Javascript encode functions:

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/

There is also a good discussion about the techniques as well.

Cheers,

[www.greyhound-computing.com](http://www.greyhound-computing.com)